# Кликабельный элемент на кликабельном элементе

Tags: javascript, html, html5

У меня есть некий квадрат размером 200на200 пикселей, если по нему нажать то мы перейдем в определенное окно, а еще в правом верхнем углу этого квадрата есть красный квадрат размером 20на20 пикселей, и при нажатии на него нужно выполнить другое действия, но получаеться так что при нажатии на красный квадрат выполняеться сразу два действия

Comment: Код напишите, который у вас есть.

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.querySelector(".big-square").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("click on big-square");
});
document.querySelector(".small-square").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("click on small-square");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.big-square {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.small-square {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: pink;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-square">
  <div class="small-square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('.parent').onclick = function (e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('child')){
    alert('click on child element');
  } else {
    alert('click on parent element');
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.child {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```